British or Celtic folklore fantasy book from the 80s
Searching for a book I read in the 80s. It featured Fae/fairy woodland type characters, one of which had a torn wing. They lived in a forest that was slowly shrinking as the modern world encroached on it, and they started looking for a new place to live. I dimly remember the cover being quite dark, and had a character with rainbow/iridescent wings. The characters used an old English method of counting - Yan, tan, tethera, etc. I believe it was a children's book, on a similar level to Narnia, Watership Down, and the like

Unrelated to your question, but Watership Down isn't exactly a children's book, and IMO neither are the Narnia series.

Respectfully, I disagree. The Narnia books are considered classic children's literature, and Richard Adams wrote Watership Down for his daughters.

Reminds me a bit of De Lint's entry to Brian Froud's Faerielands series. Though these were '90s and perhaps a bit more adult/YA. Agree, Chris - I too consider Narnia and Watership to be children's lit. I read them between 8-10 years old, enjoyed them immensely, and have returned to them to find them best for kids.
